Define a command with keys as arguments AND allow the default values depend on each other
Is there a way to define a command\foo taking a key list as its argument AND have the following feature:

The default values of some of the keys (saying, b and c) rely on some other keys (saying, a).

For a command with arguments, I know how to do it. But I'm not familiar with key systems.
Here is an example:
\NewDocumentCommand\foo{mO{b#1b}O{c#1c}}{#1 is a, #2 is b, and #3 is c.}

So \foo{a=xxx} should work as \foo{xxx}, producing ''xxx is a, bxxxb is b, and cxxxc is c.'', while \foo{a=xxx,b=yyy} should work as \foo{xxx}[yyy].

yes, that's fairly straightforward. however, you've provided no code which might indicate which key-value system you are using and no minimal example which someone might use to demonstrate any method.

A modification of campa's answer which requires no packages.
\documentclass{article}
\NewDocumentCommand\foo{mO{b#1b}O{c#1c}}{#1 is a, #2 is b, and #3 is c.}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { gausyu }
{
  a .tl_set:N = \l_gausyu_a_tl,
  a .initial:n = {a},
  b .tl_set:N = \l_gausyu_b_tl,
  c .tl_set:N = \l_gausyu_c_tl,
}
\NewDocumentCommand \gausyufoo { +m }
{
  \group_begin:
    \keys_set:nn { gausyu }
    {
      b = { b \l_gausyu_a_tl b },
      c = { c \l_gausyu_a_tl c },
      #1,
    }
    \l_gausyu_a_tl{}  ~ is ~ a, ~
    \l_gausyu_b_tl{}  ~ is ~ b
    ~ and ~
    \l_gausyu_c_tl{}  ~ is ~ c
  \group_end:
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\foo{xxx}

\foo{xxx}[yyy]
\medskip

\gausyufoo{a=xxx}

\gausyufoo{a=xxx,b=yyy}

\gausyufoo{c=zebra,a=aardvark,b=bonobo}

\gausyufoo{}

\end{document}


Surely newer kernels offer other approaches, but here a old-fashioned one.
\documentclass{article}

\NewDocumentCommand\foo{mO{b#1b}O{c#1c}}{#1 is a, #2 is b, and #3 is c.}

\usepackage{keyval}
\makeatletter
\define@key{foo}{a}[1]{\def\foo@a{#1}}
\define@key{foo}{b}[1]{\def\foo@b{#1}}
\define@key{foo}{c}[1]{\def\foo@c{#1}}
\newcommand*{\varfoo}[1]{%
   \begingroup
   \def\foo@b{b\foo@a b}%
   \def\foo@c{c\foo@a c}%
   \setkeys{foo}{#1}%
   \foo@a\ is a, \foo@b\ is b, and \foo@c\ is c.%
   \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\foo{xxx}\par
\foo{xxx}[yyy]\vskip3ex
\varfoo{a=xxx}\par
\varfoo{a=xxx,b=yyy}

\end{document}


The main idea is that first you define the "defaults", and then evaluate the keys.

The approach shown in the other answers is applicable in all key=value parsers that support storage in a macro (so in practice all of them). The basic idea is storing the value of a in a macro and using that macro as the initial value of the other keys.
However in key=value frontends that only work by argument forwarding (expkv-cs) this is not an easy thing to do (without quite a bit of underlying code allowing this functionality in a user-perceived easy syntax). For this to work we need a second auxiliary we pass the altered values to (in the meantime @egreg has posted an answer with a similar approach):
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expkv-cs}
\NewDocumentCommand\argfoo{mO{b#1b}O{c#1c}}{#1 is a, #2 is b, and #3 is c.}
\ekvcSplit\keyfoo
  {
     a = a % #1
    ,v: b = c_novalue_tl % #2
    ,v: c = c_novalue_tl % #3
  }
  {%
    \ExpandArgs{nee}\fooAux{#1}
      {\unexpanded\IfValueTF{#2}{{#2}}{{b#1b}}}
      {\unexpanded\IfValueTF{#3}{{#3}}{{c#1c}}}%
  }
\newcommand\fooAux[3]
  {#1 is a, #2 is b, and #3 is c.}

\begin{document}
\argfoo{xxx}\par
\keyfoo{a=xxx}

\argfoo{xxx}[yyy]\par
\keyfoo{a=xxx,b=yyy}

\argfoo{xxx}[yyy][zzz]\par
\keyfoo{a=xxx,b=yyy,c=zzz}

\argfoo{xxx}[bxxxb][zzz]\par
\keyfoo{a=xxx,c=zzz}
\end{document}



I'd initialize the to-be-filled-in keys to a special value (expl3 provides \q_no_value for the job). After setting the keys as specified in the argument, we can check whether b and c has been set by testing against the special value and act as desired.
Here the function \__gausyu_foo_fill:Nnnn can adorn the main argument (the second one) with a prefix (third argument) and postfix (fourth argument); I actually use \__gausyu_foo_fill:NVnn in order to get the actual value and not the container (contrary to what happens in campa's and cfr's answers).
\documentclass{article}

\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{mO{b#1b}O{c#1c}}{%
  \par
  \addvspace{1ex}
  a is #1 (\texttt{\detokenize{#1}})\par
  b is #2 (\texttt{\detokenize{#2}})\par
  c is #3 (\texttt{\detokenize{#3}})\par
  \addvspace{1ex}
}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\keys_define:nn { gausyu/foo }
 {
  a .tl_set:N  = \l_gausyu_a_tl,
  a .initial:n = {a},
  b .tl_set:N  = \l_gausyu_b_tl,
  b .initial:n = \q_no_value,
  c .tl_set:N  = \l_gausyu_c_tl,
  c .initial:n = \q_no_value,
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\keyfoo}{m}
 {
  \group_begin:
  % set the keys
  \keys_set:nn { gausyu/foo } {#1}
  % fill in the unspecified ones
  \__gausyu_foo_fill:NVnn \l_gausyu_b_tl \l_gausyu_a_tl {b} {b}
  \__gausyu_foo_fill:NVnn \l_gausyu_c_tl \l_gausyu_a_tl {c} {c}
  % now show their values
  \par
  \addvspace{1ex}
  a~is~\l_gausyu_a_tl \c_space_tl (\texttt{\tl_to_str:V \l_gausyu_a_tl})\par
  b~is~\l_gausyu_b_tl \c_space_tl (\texttt{\tl_to_str:V \l_gausyu_b_tl})\par
  c~is~\l_gausyu_c_tl \c_space_tl (\texttt{\tl_to_str:V \l_gausyu_c_tl})\par
  \addvspace{1ex}
  \group_end:
}

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__gausyu_foo_fill:Nnnn
 {
  \quark_if_no_value:NT #1 { \tl_set:Nn #1 {#3#2#4} }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__gausyu_foo_fill:Nnnn {NV}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\foo{xxx}

\foo{xxx}[yyy]

\medskip

\keyfoo{a=xxx}

\keyfoo{a=xxx,b=yyy}

\keyfoo{c=zebra,a=aardvark,b=bonobo}

\keyfoo{}

\end{document}


